# Loading a <ul> with a String array taken from an xml

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic

I am trying to make a dynamic list in HTML, I'm using a string array as data for the list, this array is OK, it has some string inside, I verified it.So this is my code:

```
function add_li(list, text) { 
var list = document.getElementById(list); 
var li = document.createElement("li"); 
li.innerHTML = text; 
list.appendChild(li); 
}


function load_list(list, list_array) { 
for (var i = 0; i < list_array.length; i++) { 
    add_li (list, list_array[i]);
} 
}
```

Here's the call:

```
load_list(lista_bodegas, Bodegas);
```

Html where the  is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>
    </title>
</head>
<body onload= "cargarBodegas();">
    <ul id= "lista_bodegas">

    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in `var list = document.getElementById(list);` you are overwriting the `list` variable - this is highly recommended against.

Comment: apart of the missing quotes in `load_list('lista_bodegas', Bodegas)`... I don't see any problem... What is the issue that you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
load_list("lista_bodegas", Bodegas);
```

instead of

```
load_list(lista_bodegas, Bodegas);
```